# Ionic type conversion from string to number

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am pretty new to ionic and mobile development in general and I am working on a project that has a property with a  string value within an ionic segment. This ion segment contains two ion-segment buttons, one button's value is '1'  for Yes , and the other button's value '2' for No. When the user taps the yes button a comment section is enable, if the user taps the no button the comment section is disabled.  This property value is binded to the property on a model page using using ngModel. This property value then needs to be converted to a number value when being submitted to a backend in a JSON payload upon submission of the payload. I find that if I just declare this property as a number, it breaks the comment enable/disable functionality and when the value is being submitted it still sends the property as a string value. I am looking for a way to convert the property value from string to number upon submission of the JSON payload.

This is what I currently have:

Property value , declared on model page named formPS4588

```
public safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated: any = '0';
```

HTML file

```
<ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider class="form-header">
      Safe Work Practices`
    </ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item>
        <p>
            S42 Safe work practices were demonstrated
        </p>
        <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="form.safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated">
            <ion-segment-button value="1" >Yes</ion-segment-button>
            <ion-segment-button value="2" (ionSelect)="tapSafeWorkPracticesNo()">No</ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label stacked>Safe Work Practice Recognition</ion-label>
        <ion-textarea autoresize placeholder="Safe Work Practice Recognition" [disabled]="disableSafeWorkPractices()"
                      [(ngModel)]="form.safeWorkPracticeRecognition"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

TS file

```
public disableSafeWorkPractices(): boolean {
    return (this.form as FormPS4588).safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated !== '1';
}


private submitForm(): void {
    console.log('submitForm()');
    this.form.updateObservationTimeTo();

    let safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated = this.formPS4588.safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated;

    this.formPS4588.change(safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated);

    this.observation.confirmSubmitted();

    this.backendService.postObservation(this.observation, this.form).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);

        this.scheduledObservation.confirmSubmitted();

        this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: result,
            duration: 1000
        }).present();

        this.exitForm();
    });
}
```

conversion function , declared on model page named formPS4588

```
public change(safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated: any): void {
    Number(safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing wrong is that you are not actually changing the value.
Instead of this:

```
this.formPS4588.change(safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated);
```

You should do something like this:

```
this.safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated = Number(safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, but when I implement the changes recommended I get an error when trying to submit the JSON payload the error is TypeError:null is not an object(evaluating 'this.formPS4588.safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated')

Comment: I think I should clarify that the submitForm() function is declared on a parent typescript file called baseForm. This baseForm file is the parent class for 4 different form options that can be submitted. One of these children forms is formPS4588. This is the only form that contains the property safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated that needs to be converted from a string to a number upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to implement a solution by tying a conversion function for the property value when the user taps the submit button for the submission of the form.

```
<ion-item-group padding>
    <button ion-button block [disabled]="!isObservationCriteriaMet()" (tap)="doSubmit(); change();">Submit</button>
</ion-item-group>

public change(): void {

    (this.form as FormPS4588).safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated = Number((this.form as FormPS4588).safeWorkPracticesWereDemonstrated);

}
```